# How to make Qt agree with GTK monitor number?

Tags: c++, qt, gtk, screen, x11

I'm trying to access an X11 property set per-monitor by a GTK application. The name of the property depends on the monitor number. The application accessing the property uses Qt. Now, it appears that Qt numbers the monitors differently than GTK, so when I retrieve the property from the Qt program, it gets the one for wrong monitor, because for some reason GTK and Qt don't agree non monitor numbering.

To confirm this, I've made two tests to check what GTK and Qt give me for the same monitor. Here's my test GTK code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    const auto widget=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show(widget);
    while(gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();

    const auto window=gtk_widget_get_window(widget);
    const auto screen=gdk_window_get_screen(window);
    const auto monitor=gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_window(screen,window);
    std::cout << "GTK monitor number: " << monitor << "\n";
}
```

And here's the Qt code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget;
    widget.show();
    app.processEvents();

    const auto desktop=app.desktop();
    std::cout << "Qt screen number: " << desktop->screenNumber(&widget) << "\n";
}
```

Here's what `xrandr` says:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0  
<...>
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300mm
   1280x1024      60.0 +   75.0* 
<...>
```

And with all this setup I get the following output from the tests when mouse cursor on the right-hand monitor:

```
Qt screen number: 0
GTK monitor number: 1
```

And the opposite when the cursor is on the left-hand monitor. Window manager is configured to place windows on the monitor where the cursor is, so indeed the same monitor is numbered differently by GTK and Qt.

So, my **question**: how do I find out monitor number which GTK's `gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_window` would return, but from a Qt application?

Comment: https://www.circuitousroot.com/artifice/programming/useful/fvwm/viewports/index.html http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qx11info.html (xcb connection) _NET_WM_DESKTOP _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS